# calculating distance to triangle/square in 2-d image

Tags: math, 2d, coordinates, distance, projection

I am programming a robot which tracks a target, and currently I am working with a sensor that can track up to four individual LED points. These points are given as 2-d locations within a pixel grid.

I am wondering if it is possible to calculate the distance from the sensor to the beacons, if they are arranged in a triangle or square of known proportions. Obviously it is easy if I am facing it dead on, but the target will be moving and potentially rotating, which would skew the perceived shape of the arrangement.

Possibly this could be done by "correcting" the shape, and then figuring out the distance based on its size?

EDIT:
Here is come clarification. Suppose I have an iPad propped up against a wall at the opposite end of a room. I take a picture of this iPad, and then, I measure the width of the iPad in the image to figure out how far the iPad was from the camera. This is fairly easy to do, since I know the actual width of the iPad and can use proportions.

But, say the iPad was turned at an angle, or flat on the floor. Then, it's not so easy to measure the width of the iPad in the image, because its shape is skewed. But, is it still possible to figure out the distance, since I know what the shape of the iPad is "supposed" to be?

Comment: Perhaps if you provide an image of what you mean it might help clarify things.

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_Pose_Estimation help?